# Phase coherence of transmitted scattering light

Tags: optics, scattering

Is it correct to state that the scattering of a laser beam in a solid inhomogeneous medium does not alter the phase coherence of the transmitted light?

Comment: Have you seen [speckle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckle_(interference))? That is a surface effect, now imagine a 3D version of it.